# Oracle Virtualbox - Can it use iso-Files?

Tags: virtualbox

I currently run Windows 7 and have Ubuntu 13.04 saved on my PC as a .iso file, I think it failed to download, but it wouldn't run in oracle Virtual Box, does this type of file work well in the virtual pc? I'm re-downloading 12.04 instead but my internet is very slow and the download is seeming endless for me, so hopefully it works

Comment: First of all VirtualBox will accept an ISO file.  Second, you might want to check the downloaded ISO, by doing an [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Virtual box is an excellent way of trying out Operating systems and can work with .iso files.

First step is to create your virtual machine setting up its RAM, Hard disk size etc.

Now you can mount the .iso image as a CD/DVD

[image]

Start the virtual machine and you can install the OS of choice.  Do not forget to remove the .iso file from the virtual drive when you have finished.

Virtual Box has a facility called "Guest Editions".  If the the guest OS you are using is Ubuntu I would recommend you do not install Guest Editions from the devices menu.  It works but the version in the Ubuntu repositories has always worked better for me.

You can install this on your virtual machine by opening a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> inside your virtual machine and typing

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

Comment: my pc's currens os is windows 7, i wanted to run ubuntu as a virtual os, but thanks for the answers, they helped a LOT

Comment: Steps are the same in Windows 7.  I have Virtual Box on both my Windows PC and My Ubuntu machine.