# How to boot from folder in virtualbox?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, directory

I just downloaded Virtualbox and I wish to know how to boot from a specific folder in my hard drive

I stored my Ubuntu (12.10) installation files in a single folder (copied it from the ISO) and unfortunately my computer doesn't have ISO utilities in it.

since I put my installation files in a folder, how do I set Virtualbox to boot from the folder with the Ubuntu installation files?

cheers

I'm using Windows as the host.

Comment: I don't think you can but Virtualbox understands iso files just mount the iso on the virtual CD rom.  See this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/290958/107450

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. It is technically possible to boot Linux from folder, but it would require GRUB or Shellx64 preinstalled and involves low-level fiddling with files (and many tools to use). From the way you ask the question I assume you lack the skill by far.

So, don't bother with it now. Just download ISO image and add it to Virtualbox machine (when you create new virtual machine, it even prompts you on first launch to provide OS ISO)